# Mockito set field when call getter

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm testing method and have a problem that my entity has a field that is null, but i need it not to be empty. I have this:

```
class MyClass {

    void myMethod() {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        String str = entity.getField(); // It's null now
        if (str == null) { //always true
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Now in test i need my field not to be null.
I tried to do the following in test:

```
Entity entity = mock(Entity.class);
when(entity.getField()).thenReturn("text");
```

But it seems, that it doesn't work. The problem is that I can't use PowerMock or refactor original class.
Is there any way I can return text or set field before `if` statement?

Comment: Is your problem that you cannot inject your `Entity` instance?

Comment: I go into `if` statement, which means, that `str` is still `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have no way of injecting a mocked `Entity` instance into your method.

You must adjust your `MyClass` so that it accepts an `Entity` object, thus allowing you to pass a mocked object for the purposes of testing. Without this, you cannot expect to be able to mock objects.

```
class MyClass {

    private Entity entity;

    public MyClass(Entity entity) {
      this.entity = entity;
    }

    void myMethod() {
        String str = entity.getField(); // It's null now
        if (str == null) { //always true
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the public facing constructor, consider adding a package-private setter method that lets you tweak the `Entity` instance. But you must store the instance as a field to allow you to change it from your test code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, "spy()" can be used instead of "when()": http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem before, what I have done is to create a separate wrapper method to inject the dependency for unit testing.

For example, in here, you can create wrapperMyMethod() to solve the issue, the code would be:

```
void wrapperMyMethod(){
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    void myMethod(entity);
}
void myMethod(Entity entity) {
    String str = entity.getField(); 
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.